# Tenderly: Invalid input type: tuple

Tags: tenderly

I am simulating a transaction in tenderly that takes a tuple (custom solidity struct) as an input type.

```
struct CustomStruct {
  uint256 cat;
  string dog; 
}

function doStuff(CustomStruct myStruct) public{
```

I'm trying to pass:

```
(123,"dog")
```

In, but I'm getting:

```
[
0:"Invalid input type: tuple"
]
```

As an error, how do I fix?

Answer (score 2):

You need to extrapolate the tuple as a json object:

```
{"cat":123,"dog":"dog"}
```